# simplexml_load_string displaying empty object php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am new to xml. I have string response from api as :

```
<PPResponse Result="000" Key="110308f9-6b67-422b-9dee-9c9da77d8197">
    <ResultMessage>Operation is succesfully completed</ResultMessage>
    <UtilityInfo>
        <UtilityCode>123</UtilityCode>
    </UtilityInfo>
    <BillInfo>
        <Bill>
            <BillNumber>110308f9-6b67-422b-9d13-1c9da77d8197</BillNumber>
            <DueDate>2015-12-10T07:31:44</DueDate>
            <Amount>100</Amount>
            <ReserveInfo>test</ReserveInfo>
            <BillParam>
                <mask>4</mask>
                <commission type="0" val="0.00" op="-" paysource="1" />
            </BillParam>
            <RefStan>123123123123</RefStan>
        </Bill>
    </BillInfo>
</PPResponse>
```

I try to convert it to xml object like this:

`

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $simple_xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
        if ($simple_xml === false) {
            echo "Failed loading XML\n";
            foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
                echo "\t", $error->message;
            }
            echo 'hi'; exit();
        }
        echo 'pass';    exit();`
```

It displays pass. Now, the error is that, when I dd($simple_xml), I get nothing as:

`libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $simple_xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
        if ($simple_xml === false) {
            echo "Failed loading XML\n";
            foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
                echo "\t", $error->message;
            }
            echo 'hi'; exit();
        }
        dd($simple_xml)`

I need to access the keys and values from the string after converting it to xml object. I think, regex is also solution, but I need to do through xml object.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Its a sort of emergency.

Comment: what does dd() function in your code ?

Comment: what happens if you replace `dd` with `var_dump` ?

Comment: it displays empty object like this                                                             `(object)[Object Name: SimpleXMLElement] [Object Identifier: #1284]`

Comment: is working great: https://eval.in/483238

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
// var_dump($xml); this will output the xml object just fine

if ($xml !== false) {
    echo "Successfuly loaded the XML" . PHP_EOL;
    print "Message: " . $xml->ResultMessage . PHP_EOL;
    print "Utility code: " . $xml->UtilityInfo->UtilityCode . PHP_EOL;
    print "Bill Amount: " . $xml->BillInfo->Bill->Amount . PHP_EOL;
}
else{
    echo "Failed loading the XML" . PHP_EOL;
    foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
        echo "\t", $error->message;
    }
}
```

Will display

```
Successfuly loaded the XML
Message: Operation is succesfully completed
Utility code: 78
Bill Amount: 0
```

use the below code to test for BOM sequence and remove it if it exists

```
$bom = pack("CCC", 0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf);
if (0 === strncmp($response, $bom, 3)) {
    echo "BOM detected - file is UTF-8" . PHP_EOL;
    $response = substr($response, 3);
}
// or
$response = str_replace("\xEF\xBB\xBF",'',$reponse);
```

Comment: `$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
var_dump($xml);` returns empty object in my case. When I do dd(gettype($xml)); , It returns type of type object.

Comment: I cant figure out, why it is responding empty object

Comment: try the code using $response as a string variable and use the contents that you gave us, is it working?

Comment: $response is already a string variable. I just want to convert it to simple xml object.

Comment: When I try to run your code, I display error like this.                                                        `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: I edited my answer to include a test for byte-order-mark and remove it from the response if it exists

Comment: Still empty object after testing with BOM.                                                     `(object)[Object Name: SimpleXMLElement] [Object Identifier: #1284]`

Answer (score -2):

I got the same problem then suddenly it came to my mind if this library is not available in my php and yes it was not in MY php Package..

[PHP Manual: SimpleXML Installation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.installation.php)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30561453)